# Comparing dates in same column oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have the below table

| Project No | STAGES | completion date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PROJ_001 | 1 | 12-MAR-21 |
| PROJ_001 | 2 | 14-MAR-21 |
| PROJ_001 | 3 | 15-MAR-21 |
| PROJ_001 | 4 | 18-MAR-21 |
| PROJ_002 | 1 | 18-MAR-21 |
| PROJ_002 | 2 | 19-MAR-21 |
| PROJ_002 | 3 | 19-MAR-21 |
| PROJ_002 | 4 | 23-MAR-21 |

Assuming the table is ordered by project no and stages.
I have to check whether the date in stage 1 is less than stage 2
similarly date of stage 2 should be less than stage 3
and date of stage 3 should be less than stage 4.

This should happen for all the stages in a project.

| Project No | STAGES | completion date | output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PROJ_001 | 1 | 12-MAR-21 | Correct |
| PROJ_001 | 2 | 14-MAR-21 | Correct |
| PROJ_001 | 3 | 15-MAR-21 | correct |
| PROJ_001 | 4 | 18-MAR-21 | correct |
| PROJ_002 | 1 | 19-MAR-21 | incorrect |
| PROJ_002 | 2 | 17-MAR-21 | incorrect |
| PROJ_002 | 3 | 16-MAR-21 | correct |
| PROJ_002 | 4 | 23-MAR-21 | correct |

here stage 1 of project 2 is not less than stage 2 so it is incorrect.
by default the stage 4 should be correct.

can anyone guide me with this?

Comment: There are more complex situations that you must tell us about. For example, what if the dates for stage 1, stage 2 and stage 3 are in the exact reverse order? Is stage 2 OK in that case (only stages 1 and 3 are wrong)? Or do you consider all three to be wrong? Meaning that, essentially, stages **between** two stages that are "wrong" must **all** be considered as "wrong"?

Comment: Stated differently: if you look at one particular stage and you must determine if it is "correct" or not, here are two ways to look at it (with very different results in most cases): (1) Just look to see if its position in the "time sequence" equals its stage number; if it does, call it "correct". (2) (much more strict) Look to see if all the earlier stages have earlier completion dates (than this row), and all later stages have later completion dates. Only if **all** these conditions are true, call the row "correct". In this interpretation, far fewer rows may be considered "correct".

Comment: Third possibility (also with different results from both (1) and (2) above, in general): A row is "correct" if all the **earlier** stages are already completed; don't look at the **later** stages to compare. **IMPORTANT NOTE**: You as the programmer shouldn't decide which of these choices is the correct business problem for your users. Unless you already know THEIR definition of the problem (and you can share it with us), **don't guess**. Ask the business users to clarify the question.

Comment: Hi Mathguy, If stages between two stages are "wrong" then all must not be considered as wrong.

Comment: More observations. First, the data in your "desired output" doesn't match the first set of data. Namely, the completion dates for the second project are completely different. Second, in the "desired output" the date for the second project, for Stage 3, is the earliest date for the entire project. How can that be "correct"? Your problem makes sense, but your illustration doesn't make any sense. It looks like you didn't pay much attention to it.

Comment: hi @mathguy, here the stages are completed in parallel. so stage 3 can be completed earlier than stage 2/stage 1. stage 4 is just one small process so it is always completed on time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a stage is "correct" if its time-sequence order equals the stage number, then the problem is trivial. In answer to questions I asked, the OP said that "If stages between two stages are "wrong" then all must not be considered as wrong". I interpret this to mean: A stage is "correct" if its order in the time sequence equals the stage number.

The `output` column can be populated by comparing the stage number to the sequence number, directly in a `case` expression. Like so:

```
select project_no, stage, completion_date,
       case row_number() over (partition by project_no
                               order     by completion_date, stage)
            when stage then 'correct' else 'incorrect' end as output
from   the_table
order  by {whatever}  --  if needed
;
```

Note that in the sample data there are sometimes equal values in the `completion_date` column. In that case, I assume the stages were completed in the correct order (so, the second criterion in the `order by` clause of the `row_number()` analytic function).

Comment: Thanks a ton @mathguy.. i have used the same and it worked.